# Prisma types not recognized (SvelteKit)

Tags: orm, svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I'm newbie in Prisma and SvelteKit so I started a little project and I'm trying to develop the login logic.

With the following `User` model into 'schema.prisma':

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("SECRET_DATABASE_URL")
}
    model User {
  id         Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  email      String   @unique
  name       String?
  password   String
  token      String?
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  deleted    Boolean  @default(false)
  Players    Players?

  @@map("users")
}
```

I have the following logic to find user by `email` and `password`:

```
import { prisma } from '$prisma/client';

import type { LogingUser } from '$types/LogingUser';
import type { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

export const createSession = async (requestUser: LogingUser) => {
        const loginUser: Prisma.User | null = prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: requestUser.email,
                password: requestUser.password
            }
        })
}
```

The first `prisma` import it's refers to a own `PrismaClient()` instance, so the problem I have with this is at `const loginUser: Prisma.User | null = ...` because `Prisma.User` is not recognized.

Why is it needed to import types from `@primsa/client` and not from own instance? 
Why `Prisma.User` is not recognized?